# Kendo MVC Grid - Tab navigation in non editable cells

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to kendo mvc grid. I working on an mvc page where I am showing a n kendo grid in which none of the cells are editable.

The requirement is to navigate between the cells while pressing the tab. can someone help me here?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<History>()
        .Name("grid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = " max-width: 950px ; width: auto " })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.JobName).Title("Job Name").Width(150);
            columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Title("File Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ExecutionOn).Title("Execution Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ExecutionOn).Title("Execution Time").Format("{0:h:mm:ss tt}").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ExecutionStatus).Title("Execution Status").Width(110);
        })
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100})
                )
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
         .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
        .ColumnMenu()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "History"))
        )
    )
```

Comment: you want to add link in non-Edit able cell??

Comment: it is not link, want to just highlight the cells when user presses tab.

Comment: :Please use each loop in script for changing color

Comment: Please read my ask carefully.